# Choosing install language programmatically in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup as an installer for my program, but I want to be able to choose the default language for the installer itself. I know it chooses default based on system locale (based on a list of languages I've chosen to support), but I would want to select the language according to my rules.

The rules is that for "Norwegian" and "English" OS, I want to show Norwegian, while all other gets defaulted to their own.

After loads of Googling I have not found an answer to this, and it's very possible it just can't be done. But I am also aware that Inno Setup's documentation is rather lacking, so I'm hoping maybe someone knows something which is not written down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Disable the standard language dialog by setting the [`ShowLanguageDialog`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_showlanguagedialog) to `no`.
- Do your "language decision logic" in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).
- Re-launch the installer with [`/LANG` switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=LANG).

Basically you can use the code from below question, except that instead of presenting a custom language selection dialog, you do your "decision logic".
[Inno Setup - Language selector with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41021292/850848)

---

Though for your trivial case, why don't you just create an "English" `.isl` ([`LanguageID` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=langoptionssection&anchor=LanguageID) set to `$0409`) with Norwegian contents?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Setup]
LanguageDetectionMethod=none
```

Setup will use the first language specified in the `[Languages]` section as the default language.

Comment: That is certainly an option, which I might have to end up going for. However, and this is due to my bad wording, it doesn't let me specify what language I want myself other than "one default for all". What I need (for reasons I find quite dumb and won't go into) is that all "Norwegian" and "English" os languages get's defaulted to Norwegian, while all other gets defaulted to their own.

Comment: So the default language will be decided at runtime?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean