# Can I swap ISSI SplashScreen and language selection dialog in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, issi

Here's my code:

```
#define ISSI_Splash "C:\InnoSetupProject\Images\client.bmp"                   
#define ISSI_Splash_T 3                                                                        
#define ISSI_Splash_X 500                                                                    
#define ISSI_Splash_Y 220 

#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI" 
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"
```

I'd like to have Splash screen shown before the language selection dialog, just when I start the installer.
Is it possible to do that without having to create my own language selection dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way in Inno Setup to do *anything* before the language selection dialog.

There's no [event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) triggered before that.

---

The only workaround is to implement your own language dialog. For an example, see:
[Inno Setup - Language selector with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41021292/850848)