# Debugging Inno Setup installer that respawns itself

Tags: inno-setup, exit-code, pascalscript, shellexecute

As it can be seen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021292/inno-setup-language-selector-with-vcl-styles) question we start a new instance of Inno Setup:

```pascal
Instance := ShellExecute(0, '', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), Params, '', SW_SHOW);
```

where

```pascal
function ShellExecute(hwnd: HWND; lpOperation: string; lpFile: string;
      lpParameters: string; lpDirectory: string; nShowCmd: Integer): THandle;
      external 'ShellExecuteW@shell32.dll stdcall';
```

All the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021292/inno-setup-language-selector-with-vcl-styles) question's answer I moved to the `VCL_Styles.iss` file and included it into my main script.

The problem is that after I've passed the `ShellExecute` call and terminate by the debugger afterwards one instance of Inno Setup keeps running (so I have to kill the process using Windows Task Manager) and I get the following messages in the `Debug Output`:

> *** Terminating process
>
> *** Removing left-over temporary directory: C:\Users\JCONST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-PV9OS.tmp
>
> *** Setup is still running; can't get exit code

instead of exit code 6 which according to the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) is returned when:

> The Setup process was forcefully terminated by the debugger (Run |
> Terminate was used in the Compiler IDE).

I'm not sure which instance of Inno Setup is still running and how can I stop it?

Here's the contents of the `VCL.Styles` that I include into my main script so I get the aforementioned error:

```pascal
[Setup]
ShowLanguageDialog=no

[Code]
function ShellExecute(hwnd: HWND; lpOperation: string; lpFile: string;
  lpParameters: string; lpDirectory: string; nShowCmd: Integer): THandle;
  external 'ShellExecuteW@shell32.dll stdcall';

<event('InitializeSetup')>
function MyInitializeSetup2: Boolean;
var
  Instance: THandle;
  I: Integer;
  S, Params, Language: String;
begin
  Result := True;

  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
      S := ParamStr(I);
      if CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), '/SL5=') <> 0 then
      begin
        Params := Params + AddQuotes(S) + ' ';
      end;
    end;

  Params := Params + '/LANG=en';
  Language := ExpandConstant('{param:LANG}');
  if Language = '' then
    begin
      Instance := ShellExecute(0, '', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), Params, '', SW_SHOW);
      if Instance <= 32 then
        begin
          S := 'Running installer with the selected language failed. Code: %d';
          MsgBox(Format(S, [Instance]), mbError, MB_OK);
        end;
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

When the debugger steps over the `ShellExecute` and the new instance of the installer process is started, the IDE debugger seems to pick that process and restarts the debugging. I assume this is not intended behaviour, or at least not a well-tested one. The *Terminate* function then probably tries to close/communicate with to the old process (which has terminated on its own meanwhile – due to its `InitializeSetup` returning `False` after the `ShellExecute`).

Martijn Laan (the current maintainer of Inno Setup) stated that Inno Setup is not designed to respawn itself. Actually Inno Setup own `Exec` API explicitly prevents respawning the installer. Bypassing this restriction by using WinAPI `ShellExecute` instead introduces the problem described in the question. It's not a surprise that the debugger cannot handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an Inno Setup's IDE bug may have caused that problem.

Here's the report link:

> https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/pDSbgD8nbxI/m/0lvTsslOAwAJ