# Change Inno Setup Select Setup Language dialog text based on the language selection

Tags: inno-setup

Based on the language selection changing selected language text.

For example: its default English text is there. But if user selected Germany, text change is required.

[image]

```
[Languages]
Name: "french"; Messages File: "compiler: Languages\French.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
#define SUPPORTED_LANGS "French,German,English"
#if SUPPORTED_LANGS != ''
#pragma message "Supported languages: " + SUPPORTED_LANGS
#else
#pragma message "Supported languages: no restriction"
#endif
#pragma

Language Selected := Expand Constant('{language}');
case Language Selected of
  'French':
    begin
      #include "fr.isl"
    end;
  'German':
    begin
      #include "de.isl"
    end;
  else
    begin
      #include "en.isl"
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard Inno Setup language selection dialog is not customizable.

If you need such customization, you have to implement your own dialog:
[Inno Setup language selector with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41021292/850848)

Comment: after customizing the screen as expected working. But procedure InitializeWizard; default buttons and default screens based on the selection not changing. how to change default screens and default buttons.

Comment: @ganesh I believe my answer to the linked question shows how to so that. If it does not work for you, we need [mcve].